# Dual simplex doubt (unrestricted)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex

I have this two problems and i only want to find the dual form:

$\begin{gather}
 max\hspace{.1cm}z =5x_1+6x_2\\
s.t\hspace{.1cm}x_1+2x_2=5\\
-x_1+5x_2 \ge 3\\
x_2 \ge 0\\
x_1\hspace{.1cm} unrestricted
\end{gather}$

$\begin{gather}
 max\hspace{.1cm}z =x_1+x_2\\
s.t\hspace{.1cm}2x_1+x_2=5\\
3x_1-x_2 =6\\
x_1, x_2 \hspace{.1cm}unrestricted
\end{gather}$

So, in dual form i have this:

$\begin{gather}
 min\hspace{.1cm}z' =5y_1-3y_2\\
s.t\hspace{.1cm}y_1+3y_2\ge 5\\
-2y_1-5y_2 \ge 6\\
y_2 \ge 0\\
\end{gather}$

$\begin{gather}
 min\hspace{.1cm}z' =5y_1+6y_2\\
s.t\hspace{.1cm}2y_1+3y_2\ge 1\\
y_1-y_2 \ge 1\\
\end{gather}$

But I do not know how to create constraints on unrestricted variables

Answer (score 1):

I have designed the dual problems according to the attached table.

***First dual problem***

$\begin{gather}
 \color{blue}{min}\hspace{.1cm} \  5y_1+3y_2\\
s.t.\hspace{.1cm} \ \ y_1-y_2= 5\\
\ \ 2y_1+5y_2 \ge 6\\
y_1 \ \text{free}, \ y_2 \le 0
\end{gather}$

***Second dual problem***

$\begin{gather}
 \color{blue}{min}\hspace{.1cm} \ 5y_1+6y_2\\
s.t.\hspace{.1cm} \ \ 2y_1+3y_2 = 1\\
y_1-y_2 = 1 \\y_1,y_2 \ \text{free}\\
\end{gather}$

If you have any questions regarding the dual formulations or the table, please feel free to ask.

[image]

Comment: that means that the unrestricted variable produces an equality in the existent constraint. I thought it generated a new equality constraint..

Comment: If you have **n** (in-)equalities and **m** variables at the primal problem, than you have **m** (in-)equalities and **n** variables at the dual problem. Thus you "add" nothing.